# XSLT insert at right location

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

My input XML is as follows. Basically the XML has various `<servlet>` tags. My requirement is to apply a XSLT transform which browses through `<servlet-name>` tags and see if a particular servlet with specified name exists. If it exists then i need to see that tag `<B>` under that particular servlet with a `<param-name>`does not EXIST. If the tag  with a specific `<param-name>` under the searched  doesn't exist then i add the tag `<B>NEW</B>` along with other `<B>` tags of that particular servlet else i do not perform any action.

**INPUT XML**

```
<web-app metadata-complete="true">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AAA</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.AAA</servlet-class>

    <B>
        <param-name>port</param-name>
        <param-value>8802</param-value>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>connectors-xml</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>webservices-xml</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>exposure-server</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <some-tag>1</some-tag>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BBB</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.BBB</servlet-class>

    <B>
        <param-name>port</param-name>
        <param-value>8802</param-value>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>connectors-xml</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>webservices-xml</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>exposure-server</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <some-tag>2</some-tag>
</servlet>

<C>
    <D>   
     </D
</C>

<junk-tag>
    <tag1>BASIC</tag1>
     <tag2>BASIC</tag2>
</junk-tag>
</web-app>
```

eg. Lets say i search for a Servlet with Servlet name as "BBB" below. If found, then i check that its `<B>` tag with `<param-name>` value XXX doesn't exist then i add it so that o/p looks as below. If "BBB" `<servlet-name>` has `<B>` tag with `<param-name>` value XXX already present then i do not do anything.

**OUTPUT.XML**

```
<web-app metadata-complete="true">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AAA</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.AAA</servlet-class>

    <B>
        <param-name>port</param-name>
        <param-value>8802</param-value>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>connectors-xml</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>webservices-xml</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>exposure-server</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <some-tag>1</some-tag>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BBB</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.BBB</servlet-class>

    <B>
        <param-name>port</param-name>
        <param-value>8802</param-value>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>connectors-xml</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>webservices-xml</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <param-name>exposure-server</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </B>

    <B>NEW</B>

    <some-tag>2</some-tag>
</servlet>

<C>
    <D>   
     </D
</C>

<junk-tag>
    <tag1>BASIC</tag1>
     <tag2>BASIC</tag2>
</junk-tag>
</web-app>
```

I have tried writing a XSLT but somehow caught in BUGS and syntax issues

```
    <xsl:template match="web-app/servlet[servlet-name='BBB/B']">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(/web-app/servlet[servlet-name='BBB']/B[param-name='XXX'])">
            <B>NEW</B>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Any guidance? I am NOVICE to XSLT and attempting by googling itself.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you want is just `not(B[param-name='XXX'])` as you are already positioned on the relevant `servlet` at the point, so this expression will be relevant to that. Additionally your current code will copy the existing `servlet` and add `<B>NEW</B>` after it, when in fact you want it as a child.

So you could do this....

```
<xsl:template match="web-app/servlet[servlet-name='BBB']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(B[param-name='XXX'])">
            <B>NEW</B>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or better still, put the check in the template match itself

```
<xsl:template match="web-app/servlet[servlet-name='BBB'][not(B[param-name='XXX'])]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <B>NEW</B>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

(Both of these assume you are also using the [identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform))

However, this adds your new tag after `<some-tag>2</some-tag>` which may not be what you want.

If you want to place it after the last `B` element, you should change the template to match the last `B` element instead.

```
<xsl:template match="web-app/servlet[servlet-name='BBB'][not(B[param-name='XXX'])]/B[last()]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <B>NEW</B>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="web-app/servlet[servlet-name='BBB'][not(B[param-name='XXX'])]/B[last()]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        <B>NEW</B>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution expands my knowledge to tackle similar issues in future.